# Looking for regular expression that will cover every "file://"

Tags: javascript, regex

I am try to create a regular expression for a javascript project that covers every hyperlink that starts with "file://"

Thanks :)

Comment: if you are just testing the contents of href attribute, do as asad says. If you are looking for file:// urls in the text, that is a different question completely. Please specify what you mean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperlinks have location properties-

you can read document.links[0].protocol from a link.

```
var links=document.links, L=links.length, filelinks=[];

while(L){
  if(links[--L].protocol=='file:')filelinks.push(links[L].href);
}

//eg:
filelinks.join('\n')


file:///C:/webworks/gallery/gallery.html
file:///C:/webworks/library/shared/dewey.html#holmes
file:///C:/webworks/library/shared/dewey.html#twain
file:///C:/webworks/library/shared/dewey.html
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Here is a very thorough version developed by [this](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) guy:</strike>

```
(?i)\b((?:file:(?:\/{2}))(?:www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9\-]+[.])?(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

EDIT: Evidently I needed to change a few things to make it more strict. I've updated it. If you want to use the capturing groups, remove the ?: to keep a backreference.

Please use the simpler, `/(file:\/{2,3}[!#$&-;=?-\[\]_a-z~]+)/`

Comment: captures whether the url is using www or ww1 or domainname or whatever. see the link for details

Comment: Only that `www` is unlikely to be part of a *local* `file://` URI, isn't it?

Comment: that is true, I'll modify it to not pick up on those. Actually, I'm going to give up on this answer, because while it does work, it doesn't work as is implicitly advertised. The simplest one is best.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

/^(file?://)?([\da-z.-]+).([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*/?$/

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks ! and I am looking for the "file://" prefix in a string and this will do the job.. thanks :)

Comment: If it's the right answer for your question, please mark this as answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/^file\/\/:/i.test(str)
str.match(/^file\/\/:\S+/i)
```

I wouldn't check for any more than the protocol, URIs are very complicated.